# Erro ao incluir atributo name em @WebService

Tags: java, java-8, jax-ws, jaxb

Estou criando a classe que implementa a chamada do WS e ao tentar incluir o atributo name, aparece este erro:

```
"@WebService annotation contains an endpointInterface attribute. No name attribute allowed"
```

Alguem sabe o motivo? Se eu retiro o atributo name, o serviço é publicado, porém com o nome da classe. 
Estou usando o Eclipse Neon e JAVA 8.

Segue abaixo, trecho do código:

[...]

```
@WebService(name="incluirConta", endpointInterface="br.com.ws.teste.prestacao.IncluirContaWSService", portName="IncluirContaWSService", serviceName="endpoints")

@Stateless public class IncluirContasImpl extends BaseServico implements IncluirContas { //metodos omitidos... }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa é uma validação específica de um plugin para JAX-WS do Eclipse ([classe](http://git.eclipse.org/c/webtools/org.eclipse.webtools.incubator.git/tree/webservices/plugins/org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.core/src/org/eclipse/jst/ws/internal/jaxws/core/JAXWSCoreMessages.properties?h=origin&id=b15c39d64e19b902954c4a58cbf00606aab48486)). Enquanto validações dão boas dicas, elas não são necessáriamente erros. O desenvolvedor da implementação JAX-WS pode fazer o que bem entender.

Dito isso, no seu caso acredito que faça realmente sentido mover o nome para a interface:

```
@WebService(name="IncluirConta",
    targetNamespace="http://algum.namespace.com",
    wsdlLocation="http://meu.dominio.com/ServicoConta?wsdl")
public interface IncluirContaSEI

@WebService(endpointInterface="br.com.ws.teste.prestacao.IncluirContaSEI",
    portName="IncluirContaPort", 
    serviceName="IncluirContaService")
public class IncluirContaPortImpl extends BaseServico implements IncluirContaSEI
```

Para mais informações consulte a documentação da sua implementação de JAX-WS. E.g., [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/developing-a-service.html#DevelopingaService-AnnotatingtheSEI)